# how to give style to first-child in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i was trying to give `margin-left:160px` to the `.item` class of the very first child but it's not giving me desired result if i'm using bootstrap `grid` system other than that it's working fine on js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ph4kq5bp/
. and i want to give `margin-left:10px` to all the other `<div class="item"></div>` instead of first child

```
   <div class="col-lg-3 item text-center">
       1
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 item text-center">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 item text-center">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 item text-center">
       4
      </div>
```

css

```
.item:first-child
{
 margin-left:160px;
}
.item 
{
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 background-color:#000;
 float:left;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked inspector? What styles/properties are overriding the .item styles?

More than likely, all you have to do is adjust the specificity of the CSS selector on .item so that it overrides the bootstrap default.

See: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of `first-child` you might want

```
.item:first-of-type
```

Updated Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ph4kq5bp/2/